# Need textbox xmlview component for c#

Tags: open-source, c#, text-editor, xml

I need a textbox component that change the color of xml values for better reading.
something like in :
[codebeauty xml validator](http://codebeautify.org/xmlvalidate)

[image]

is there any free component for use?

just want to show and edit xml. don't want bind in to treeview like others propose.
thanks